# Intense Debate Javascript Chops URL

Tags: php, javascript

Intense Debate uses the following javascript code to display a comments number on my blog, which I have included in a handy little php function.  By passing this php function the ID of a blog post, it creates a link to the comments section of that specific post.

```
function show_comments_number($id) {
$url="index.php?p=post&id=$id";
?>
<script>
var idcomments_acct = 'xxx';
var idcomments_post_id = '<? echo $id;?>';
var idcomments_post_url = '<? echo $url;?>';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.intensedebate.com/js/genericLinkWrapperV2.js"></script>
<?}
```

The problem is that Intense Debate parses the URL I'm trying to pass it, leaving off the & and everything after it.  So the link Intense Debate produces is just "index.php?p=post" -- obviously this is a problem.

Any ideas as to why it's chopping the URL in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or follow [the W3C's advice](http://www.w3.org/QA/2005/04/php-session#separator) and change & to a ; (make sure to modify your argument_separator.input and argument_separator.output accordingly).

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, the &id in your URL is being interpreted as an invalid HTML entity.  Wrapping your `<script>` tag in a comment (`<!--<script></script>//-->`) should help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `&id` to `&amp;id`, and you should solve it.